# How to encrypt a folder such that you can decrypt it on an unknown windows target system

Tags: linux, windows, encryption

I have to encrypt some files (from a linux system) and want to put them on a usb-stick and then be able to decrypt it on a windows system where I don't have admin-privileges and where I don't know which encryption software is installed.

Is there any way to do this?

- One solution might be that I use something which can be decrypted with standard windows utilities. Maybe this is the case for zip, but I cannot test it because I don't have a windows machine.
- Another option might be to use some portable version of an encryption software. But I don't know if the system allows me to run portable apps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`7-Zip`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/) to save the folder into an encrypted archive and put the needed files to run `7-Zip` from USB stick unencrypted on the stick, too.  For just getting the command line interface working without installation the afford is rather small (see [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/266c9423)).

Comment: Will I be able to run this without admin privileges? Isn't it possible to encrypt it in such a way that windows standard utilities can open it? What's about using the linux command `zip -r -P "mypassword" myfiles.zip myfiles`? Will I be able to decrypt this? I don't have a windows system to test!

Comment: I suggested `7zip` since I couldn't definitely testify that `zip`-encryption is actually secure.  Zip format v5.2 seems to be able doing AES encryption, but I don't know how wide-spread support for this is and whether Windows is able to handle it.

Comment: There's also a portable version of `7zip` available: http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=796

Comment: And isn't there any problem with running portable 7zip with restricted privileges?

Comment: Here is how to install it on linux: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/6e6f6d1b-95c3-46df-8a26-b7efd8ee4b57/entry/how_to_use_7zip_on_linux_command_line144?lang=en

Comment: And here is how I would use it to encrypt something on linux. This should then be readable on windows (which I cannot test): http://xmodulo.com/2013/09/how-to-create-encrypted-zip-file-on-linux.html

Comment: `7za a -tzip -pMY_SECRET -mem=AES256 secure.zip doc.pdf doc2.pdf doc3.pdf`

Comment: The »portable« application's premise is to be usable without needing to modify the used machine in any way, they are designed for not needing admin privileges (resp. for running in their absence).  This should work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [trucrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).

- Create an ntfs container and put your files on that.
- Copy the container file to your pendrive.
- Copy the file to your Windows pc.Via truecrypt on Windows, you can be able to decrypt that container file.

Comment: But I don't know if truecrypt is installed on the target system. And In don't think that I can execute the portable version since this seems to require admin privileges.